# How are Public Name Tags regsitered on Etherscan?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, etherscan, name-registrar

How are Public Name Tags given to contracts? Are they purchased by the team issuing the contract, who verifies them and what is the process behind it?

Also, is there a way to see what contracts got brand new Public Name Tags? Like a registry.

[image: Public Name Tag (viewable by anyone)]

Comment: It is saved on Etherscan side, nothing to do with blockchain itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the registry question. Check the API.

To set metadata about a contract, you first claim ownership of the contract which gives you an admin web interface.

1. Open an account with Etherscan (Web 2.0).
2. Claim the contract. Doing so will involve signing an off-chain message with the same account that deployed the contract. MetaMask (or similar) will prompt you to sign and then Etherscan will compare the signing address with the address that deployed the contract.

Their process associates the login account with the contract deployer, and once this association is created, they will let you edit the various fields that augment data extracted from the chain itself.

Hope it helps.